# jQueryRotate click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using the jQueryRotate.js extension to perform a rotation operation on a miniature arrow (to behave like that in os x aqua filesystems), as found here:

http://wilq32.adobeair.pl/jQueryRotate/Wilq32.jQueryRotate.html

`$(document).ready(function()
   {`

```
        var rot=$('#expand-FT078Z8').rotate({maxAngle:25,minAngle:-55, duration:570,
        easing:$.easing.easeInOutExpo,
        bind:
            [
                {"click":function(){rot[0].rotateAnimation(90);}}
            ]
        });
    });
```

although, when I add another "click" function to return the arrow to its original position, as in this fashion:

`{"click":function(){rot[0].rotateAnimation(90);}}, {"click":function(){rot[0].rotateAnimation(0);}}`

the function breaks. this follows the usage instructions, as you can add more than one event.  now, normally, i would save the state in a javascript variable, but that would seem to be outside the scope of this library.  anyone know how i might go about making this happen?  please let me know.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of this plugin and have to be honest that... I forgot to update a documentation inside a jQueryRotate.js file. Instead of using a rot[0] (very old concept) just please use $(this) - > this should work for most of the cases  :)

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, i ended up just doing a rude flip, but now that you have clarified, maybe i can put into something! :D